# AB is a chord of length 2ka of a circle of radius a. The tangents to the circle at A and B meet in C if k^7 is negligible calculate the area of ABC

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, binomial-theorem

> **AB** is a chord of length *2ka* of a circle of radius *a*. The tangents to the circle at **A** and **B** meet in **C**. Show that, if *k* is so small compared with unity that $k^7$ is negligible, the area of the triangle **ABC** is $a^2k^3+\frac12 a^2k^5$.

This image is a rough idea of what I think is going on. (**O** is the center of the circle and *b* is the length of line **AC** and **X** is the intersection point of line **OC** and chord **AB**.

[image]

The area required can be given as $k\times a\times h$
I first noticed that getting *b* in terms of *a* and *k* was possible because **Triangle OAC and Triangle OBC right-angled triangles so:**$$\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} = \frac{1}{(ka)^2}$$
$$b = \frac{ka}{1- k^2}$$

Using binomial expansion to $k^4$ I got
$$b = ka(1 + \frac{1}{2}k^2 + \frac{3k^4}{8})$$

Using this I got *h* as follows:
$$a^2 + b^2 = \sqrt{a^2-(ka)^2} +h$$
$$h = a^2 + [ka(1 + \frac{1}{2}k^2 + \frac{3k^4}{8})]^2 -a\sqrt{1-k}$$
Expanding $\sqrt{1-k}$
$$h = a^2 + [ka(1 + \frac{1}{2}k^2 + \frac{3k^4}{8})]^2-a[1-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{k^2}{8}-\frac{k^3}{16}-\frac{5k^4}{128} -\frac{7k^5}{256}]$$
Expanding the middle term ,ignoring powers of *k* higher than 5:

$$h = a^2 + k^2a^2+k^4a^2 + 1-\frac{ak}{2}-\frac{ak^2}{8}-\frac{ak^3}{16}-\frac{5ak^4}{128} -\frac{7ak^5}{256}$$
$$AREA = kah =ka^3 + k^3a^3+k^5a^3 + 1-\frac{a^2k^2}{2}-\frac{a^2k^3}{8}-\frac{a^2k^4}{16}-\frac{5a^2k^5}{128} -\frac{7a^2k^6}{256}$$

The other way I had thought of was expressing *h* using triangle **XAC** instead of **OBC** but I kept making mistakes so I opted for this instead.
I simply need a **hint or a general idea** of any another simpler method of going about the questions regardless of any errors I may have made in my working above.

Comment: "Triangle OAB and Triangle OBA right-angled trangles" -> Why? Wouldn't triangles OAC and OBC be the right-angled triangles here, since tangents are perpendicular to the radius?

Comment: Mathematician Poincaré said "Geometry is the art of correct reasoning from incorrectly drawn pictures" ; but I advise you, another time, to have a *less incorrectly* drawn picture : angles $OAC$ and $OBC$ should be closer to right angles...

Comment: @JeanMarie: I thought it was the Greeks who said that doing geometry means knowing how to reason about false figures. Would Poincaré not have been content to relay this opinion?

Comment: @Stéphane Jaouen
 Indeed, this sentence is older than I thought at first : for example [here](https://www.apprendre-en-ligne.net/blog/index.php/2006/01/13/141-citation-de-descartes) it is (mis ?)attributed to Descartes...

Comment: Is the answer wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In right triangle $OXB$, Pythagoras theorem gives :

$$OX^2+(ka)^2=a^2 \iff OX=a \sqrt{1-k^2}\tag{1}$$

In right triangle $OBC$, let us use the ["Geometric mean theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem) stating that the length of altitude $BX$ is the geometric mean of the length of segments it creates on the hypotenuse , i.e., $OX$ and $XC$ :

$$OX.XC=XB^2 \iff XC=\frac{(XB)^2}{OX}=\frac{k^2a^2}{a \sqrt{1-k^2}}=\frac{k^2a}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}$$

As the area $\Delta$ of triangle $ABC$ is $XB.XC$, it remains to expand :

$$\Delta=ka.\frac{k^2a}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}=k^3a^2 (1-k^2)^{-1/2}$$

into a [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) (as you have done) :

$$\Delta=k^3a^2(1+\tfrac12 k^2+...)$$

where the first omitted term is negligible.

Comment: Remark : the result about the geometric mean is a direct consequence of the fact that right triangles $OXB$ and $OBC$ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

$\square OACB$ is a kate with $\angle A=\angle B =90^\circ$ and $OA=OB=a.$ Since $\angle O=2k$, $AC=BC=a\tan k$ and $\angle C=\pi-2k$.

The area wanted is then $(ACB)=\frac12ABAC\sin\angle C=a^2\tan^2k\sin2k=a^2\sin^3k\sec k=a^2k^3+O(k^7).$